# How to refresh an AppWidget on MODE_NIGHT_FOLLOW_SYSTEM?

Tags: android, android-appwidget, theme-daynight

I'm trying to automatically refresh appWidget's layout when user changes Day/Night mode.

I have my "day layout" into layout folder, and my "night layout" into layout-night folder.

It's the good layout when the AppWidget just installed... but layout never changes when I change Day/Night's mode.

```
AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_FOLLOW_SYSTEM );
```

is set in my Application class.

How to detect the system's Day / Night mode change into an AppWidget to refresh it, please ?

Comment: What Android version are you testing this on?

Comment: Android 9 - Galaxy Note 10

Comment: I would argue that it is the launcher's responsibility to detect the dark mode change and tell all the app widgets to update using the normal update communications path.

Comment: Thanks for yours responses. Same things happens with Gmail's appWidget.... but Google Now's appWidget well follows mode :/ I will try with another smartphone or launcher.